# Finding MLE of standard deviation and asymptotic variance of the estimator

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, maximum-likelihood, standard-deviation

Variables *$X_{1}, . . . , X_{n}$* - random sample from normal distribution, $N(0,\theta)$. There I need to find:

- the MLE of standard deviation of *$X_{1}$*;
- the asymptotic variance of the estimator we found in the previous step.

I made my own calculations but I'm not sure neither with the final results nor with the used methods of getting them. Here's what I did:

I found the MLE of $\theta$: $\hat{\theta} = \bar{X^2}$ **(where $\bar{X^2}$ is the second raw sample moment)**.Then, I used the relation between $g(\hat{\theta})$ and $g(\theta)$ and assumed that the MLE of $\hat{\sigma}$ ( standard deviation of *$X_{1}$*) would be $\sqrt {\bar{X^2} } $. What about the asymptotic variance of $\hat{\sigma}$, I'm stuck - I found Var$(\hat{\theta})$ $= \left(\frac{2\theta^2}{n}\right)$ $= I^{-1}(\theta) $ and guessed that with the asymptotic distribution the asymptotic variance must be $ \left(\frac{2(\sqrt {\bar{X^2} })^2}{n}\right)$.

So, could someone, please, help?

Additional thoughts:

Alternatively, I tried to calculate the MLE of $\hat{\sigma}$ from scratch  by using $$\sum_{i=1}^n ln[f(x_{i},\sigma^2)] = l$$
Then I took the first and second derivative to estimate the MLE of $\hat{\sigma}$ which was indeed $\sqrt {\bar{X^2} } $. However, while getting the $ I(\sigma) = -E(\frac{d^2 l}{d\sigma^2}) = -E(\frac{-2n}{\sigma^2}) = \frac{2n}{\sigma^2}$, therefore,  the asymptotic variance is $ \left(\frac{(\sqrt {\bar{X^2} })^2}{2n}\right)$. Thus, either my original assumptions were incorrect in the first place, or I incorrectly calculated in the second.

Comment: You should check your calculations for the MLE of $\theta$. I'm getting an MLE of $\theta$ to be $\frac{X_1^2+\dots+X_n^2}{n}$ which is approximately $\mathcal{N}\left(\theta,\frac{2\theta^2}{n}\right)$ when $n$ is large.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew, for joining! Yes, I got the same - as I wrote, the MLE of  is the second raw sample moment. And I got the same distribution for the variable.

Comment: $\bar{X}$ is conventional notation for the sample mean, $\frac{X_1 + \dots + X_n}{n}$. If you're using $\bar{X}$ to denote something other than the sample mean, I would make this explicit in your post to prevent any confusion. Saying that your MLE is $\bar{X}^2$ makes it seem like you're saying that the MLE is $(\text{sample mean})^2$ which confused me.

Comment: Yes, got it, thanks - just clarified it in the sentence.

Comment: Have you considered $\delta-$method? You know that $\hat{\theta}=\frac{X_1^2+\dots + X_n^2}{n}$ satisfies $$\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\theta}-\theta\right)\longrightarrow_d\mathcal{N}\Big(0,(\theta\sqrt{2})^2\Big)$$

Taking $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ in the $\delta-$method yields $$\sqrt{n}\Big(\sqrt{\hat{\theta}} - \sqrt{\theta}\Big)\longrightarrow_d \mathcal{N}\left(0,\theta/2\right)$$ which implies your asymptotic variance of $\sqrt{\hat{\theta}}$ is $\frac{\theta}{2n}$

Comment: Thanks, Matthew, got it all!